# How to Place a FAB at the end of a View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout, floating-action-button

I'm trying to create a layout like below.

The problem is that the FAB is changing position in some devices because i have hardcoded the bottom margin.

I want the FAB as like in the below image.

**PRESENT CODE**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mlogin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/selfiel" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Login"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />

                <!-- Email Label -->
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/input_email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Email"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <!-- Password Label -->
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/input_password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/forgot"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="103dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/forgot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Forgot password?"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:onClick="submit"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: a FAB here looks weird

Comment: What is the result of your current code? Please post a screenshot.

Comment: The above screenshot is the current result. But FAB position is changing in other devices.

Comment: could you explain me which devices you use, and which one of these has wrong view

Comment: For the record, for this layout putting the FAB anywhere other than where it currently is would look weird. I think it looks great! It would seem unbalanced if it were on the right side of the card as we typically see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the CoordinatorLayout.

The basic layout would be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/mlogin">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/selfiel" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Login"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />

                <!-- Email Label -->
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/input_email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Email"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <!-- Password Label -->
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/input_password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="bottom">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Forgot password?"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/submit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:text="Sign Up"
                android:onClick="submit"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/card"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The magic lines here are in the FloatingActionButton that say:

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/card"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
```

This essentially tells your layout that the FAB is related to the card, and that it should be positioned relative to the card (centered at the bottom).

You can find the CoordinatorLayout documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html), and a pretty good tutorial [here](https://lab.getbase.com/introduction-to-coordinator-layout-on-android/).

Best of luck!

Comment: FAB works great. But the Textview & Button are hidden ?

Comment: Yeah, you were right. I've edited my answer to reflect the appropriate changes. You'll notice I also trimmed out some unnecessary attributes in some of your views. The trick was to actually include the "forgot" link and the button inside of the AppBarLayout. I put them them inside of a LinearLayout so I could take advantage of the following lines:

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom"

Answer (score 0):

use android:layout_gravity="bottom" instead Then adjust with margins if you want.  so you can do this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/forgot"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />
```